# heroku /api/comments:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, react-redux

I just pushed the latest to heroku and when testing the new comment functionality I got 500. Everything works fine on localhost. In the attached log it referencing jbuilder and it looks like the comments do not exit. Does anybody know what might cause it?

```
json.extract! comment, :id, :body, :author_id, :video_id, :created_at

@comments.each do |comment| 
  json.set! comment.id do 
    json.partial! 'comment', comment: comment 
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the migrations? `heroku run rake db:migrate --app myApp`